# Bootstrap modal bind event with handler function but no return type

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I am check boostrap modal source code, and wondering if `$this.is(':visible') && $this.trigger('focus')` return the object, then the following code

```
  $target.one('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    $this.is(':visible') && $this.trigger('focus')
  })
```

will be

```
  $target.one('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
     [Object object]
  })
```

what does this code mean?

Comment: It is not really equivalent. The function calls for `is` and `trigger` are made (ignoring shortcuts at this moment). The variables are not stored nor returned. Getting back to the shortcutting: `focus` is only triggered when `visible` is true. So no values are actually returned frome `one`, it's just a callback. .... does this makes sense?

Comment: so it is equivalent to `if($this.is(':visible')){ $this.trigger('focus')}`?

Comment: Yes, but its not a nice way to write it. The correct term is `short-circuiting` (not shortcutting, my bad). As for after your edit: different languages can interpret objects as booleans: in C++ everything evaluates to `TRUE` if its not `0`. For VB6; false = 0, true = -1, and everything else is undetermined. Maybe this post about javascript helps you out: http://www.grauw.nl/blog/entry/510